# How to resolve this error “Divide by zero ”

Tags: sql

I am working on some SQL query but it's throwing an error:

Divide by zero error encountered.

I believe this part is causing this problem:

```
select DataDoc as Data,
numdoc as NºDoc, cabeccompras.Matricula As Matricula,CDU_PesoBrtTotDoc as PesoBruto, CDU_PesoLiqTotDoc as PesoLiquido, 
CDU_VolumeTotlDoc as VolumeTotal, Viaturas.CDU_CapacidadeM3 as CapacidadeCamião,(CDU_VolumeTotlDoc - Viaturas.CDU_CapacidadeM3) AS [Vazio], 
convert(nvarchar,CAST(100 -(cast(cdu_volumetotldoc as decimal(12,2) ) * 100 / cast(Viaturas.CDU_CapacidadeM3 as decimal(12,2))) AS DECIMAL (12,2))) + '%' AS "Percentagem Vazio",Viaturas.CDU_TipoViat as Tipo_Viatura
from CabecCompras
inner join viaturas on CabecCompras.matricula=Viaturas.matricula
where tipodoc='VGR'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below using `NULLIF()` function

```
select DataDoc as Data,
numdoc as NºDoc, cabeccompras.Matricula As Matricula,CDU_PesoBrtTotDoc as PesoBruto, CDU_PesoLiqTotDoc as PesoLiquido, 
CDU_VolumeTotlDoc as VolumeTotal, Viaturas.CDU_CapacidadeM3 as CapacidadeCamião,(CDU_VolumeTotlDoc - Viaturas.CDU_CapacidadeM3) AS [Vazio], 
convert(nvarchar,CAST(100 -(cast(cdu_volumetotldoc as decimal(12,2) ) * 100 / nullif(cast(Viaturas.CDU_CapacidadeM3 as decimal(12,2))) AS DECIMAL (12,2))),0) + '%' AS "Percentagem Vazio",
Viaturas.CDU_TipoViat as Tipo_Viatura
from CabecCompras
inner join viaturas on CabecCompras.matricula=Viaturas.matricula
where tipodoc='VGR'
```

Comment: This was my first choice, however it always gives syntax error next to  ).

Comment: Solved select DataDoc as Data,
numdoc as NºDoc, cabeccompras.Matricula As Matricula,CDU_PesoBrtTotDoc as PesoBruto, CDU_PesoLiqTotDoc as PesoLiquido, 
CDU_VolumeTotlDoc as VolumeTotal, Viaturas.CDU_CapacidadeM3 as CapacidadeCamião,(CDU_VolumeTotlDoc - Viaturas.CDU_CapacidadeM3) AS [Vazio],
 convert(nvarchar(255),
        convert(decimal(12, 2),
                ((100.0 * cdu_volumetotldoc) / nullif(CDU_CapacidadeM3, 0)
               )
        ) -100)+ '%' As '%Vazio',
  
  
  
  Viaturas.CDU_TipoViat as Tipo_Viatura

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is to use `nullif()`.  However, never use `varchar` and related types with no length.  The default length varies by context (in SQL Server) and having the wrong length can introduce hard-to-debug errors.

So, instead of:

```
convert(nvarchar,CAST(100 -(cast(cdu_volumetotldoc as decimal(12,2) ) * 100 / cast(Viaturas.CDU_CapacidadeM3 as decimal(12,2))) AS DECIMAL (12,2))) + '%' AS "Percentagem Vazio",Viaturas.CDU_TipoViat as Tipo_Viatura
```

You presumably want:

```
convert(nvarchar(255),
        convert(decimal(12, 2),
                (100.0 - cdu_volumetotldoc) / nullif(CDU_CapacidadeM3, 0)
               )
        ) + '%' AS [Percentagem Vazio],
```

Note that this converts to the `decimal` *after* the division.  This may seem like a minor change, but I am guessing that is the result you want from the calculation, rather than the types that you want going into it.